# Excel Autocomplete column without clicking any cells

Tags: excel, autocomplete, automation, autofill

I just got a spreadsheet with about 30 k rows and 20 columns. When I updated the formula in cell C1, the whole column C get updated itself. I didn't have to click or drag anything. Does anybody know how I could turn this function off? Thanks!

Comment: The reason I wanted to remove the function is because it's not allowing me to move the columns around. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you working in a table? Or just "plain" data?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure, it's in a format that I have never seen before. I have never seen columns that update themselves without clicking on the first cell. Thanks!

Comment: Check out [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c), does any of that ring true? AFAIK in a Table, when you put a formula in, it will apply it to that column.  Does your formula look like `=SUM(DeptSales[Sales Amount])` instead of say `=Sum(A1)`?

Comment: yes, that's it ! Thank you ! : )